# Zip and password protect file using batch file - what am I missing in this code please

Tags: batch-file, winzip

```
  @echo off
    pushd "S:\SourcePath"
    "c:\program files\winzip\wzzip.exe" -a "S:\Destination\Sample.zip" *.txt  
    popd
```

I think I am missing an additional line in this code to encrypt with a password.

I have added the option of -s before I posted this but it just falls over

```
  @echo off
    pushd "S:\SourcePath"
    "c:\program files\winzip\wzzip.exe" -a "S:\Destination\Sample.zip" -spassword *.txt  
    popd
```

Comment: When you install the winzip command line addon, it also installs a help file.   You can use the **-s** and **-yc** options.

Comment: So what is stopping you from using the **-s** option with a password?

Comment: Exactly what error does it give you? `-spassword` is the correct way to add a password to a zip file.

Comment: I just tried your code exactly you you have it and I had no problems zipping a file with a password.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing wrong.  I assume you are somehow obfuscating examples.

Zipfiles.bat

```
@echo off
pushd "S:\SourcePath"
"c:\program files\winzip\wzzip.exe" -a "S:\Destination\Sample.zip" -spassword *.txt  
popd
```

And my output running from the command line.

```
C:\BatchFiles\zip>dir s:\sourcepath\*.* /b
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

C:\BatchFiles\zip>zipfiles.bat
WinZip(R) Command Line Support Add-On Version 4.0 64-bit (Build 10562)
Copyright (c) 1991-2013 WinZip International LLC - All Rights Reserved


Adding file1.txt
Adding file2.txt
Adding file3.txt
Total bytes=21, Compressed=63 -> -199 percent savings.

Copying Zip file "S:\Destination\Sample.zip".


C:\BatchFiles\zip>dir s:\destination\*.* /b
Sample.zip

C:\BatchFiles\zip>cd /D S:\Destination

S:\Destination>"C:\program files\winzip\wzunzip.exe" -spassword Sample.zip
WinZip(R) Command Line Support Add-On Version 4.0 64-bit (Build 10562)
Copyright (c) 1991-2013 WinZip International LLC - All Rights Reserved

Zip file: Sample.zip


Extracting file1.txt
Extracting file2.txt
Extracting file3.txt

S:\Destination>dir /b
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
Sample.zip

S:\Destination>
```